# How can I remove unmapped MYSQL databases using InnoDB tables with a safe bash command?

Tags: mysql, bash

```
$ user=jocular; cat ~/list|while read db; do echo rm -vi /var/lib/mysql/$user_$db; done
```

That is what I came up with but my instructor gave me this feedback :

> Removing MySQL databases in this manner can cause catastrophic problems for the MySQL server that can lead to loss of the MySQL server. Remove a database using InnoDB tables in this fashion and attempt to restore it from a backup to learn more.

What would be the safest command to remove the unmapped databases ?

Answer (score 0):

Your instructor is right, InnoDB makes it harder to manipulate tables and databases using shell tools. The reason is that InnoDB manages a "data dictionary" inside the ibdata1 file, which catalogs the databases and tables and which tablespace files they belong in. If you move or rename or delete files in the shell, InnoDB's data dictionary now references out-of-date information, and subsequently trying to use those table names or database names runs into conflicts.

> Sort of like when you get a new phone, and you keep getting calls from friends of the former owner of that phone number.

If you use SQL or other MySQL commands to drop the database, InnoDB makes sure to update its data dictionary and keep it in sync with reality.

```
user=jocular; cat ~/list | while read db; do mysqladmin drop "${user}_${db}" ; done
```

Mysqladmin prompts you before dropping a database, since there's no undoing that change. But you can also use the `-f` option to force dropping without prompting. Just be careful you don't drop the wrong database!

Comment: You could use `while read -r db; do ...; done < ~/list` instead of `cat ~/list|while read db; do ...; done` ... no need to use `cat` with this kind of loop ;)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann, true, this solution could be called out for its [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat), but I wanted to make the alternative solution as similar as possible the OP's example. The format may also be using cat only as a placeholder, where the real source of the list of databases is another command, which would justify the usage of a pipe.